# Spring boot aggregation with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

Can someone help me? I trying to use aggregation in springboot (mongodb) I have these classes:

```
   @Document
public class Ficha {
    //FIXME adicionar validacao
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Parte parte;
...}

public class Parte {
    private String nome;
    private List<Documento> documentos;
...}

public class Documento {
    private String tipo;
    private String orgaoExpedidor;
    private String numero;
...}
```

So I need to return this class:

```
public class SugestaoParte {
    private String nome;
    private String documento;

}
```

First I try the basic:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where("parte.nome").regex(".*"+ query+".*")),
            group("parte.nome").first("parte.nome").as("nome"),
            project("parte.nome")
        );

        AggregationResults<SugestaoParte> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Ficha.class, SugestaoParte.class);
        return results.getMappedResults();
```

only group by name, but my return only works if I put the _id property in my class SugestaoParte, how can I set the nome.parte to nome field??

after this I need to return , something like tis:

name = "nome.parte"
documento = "nome.parte.documento[1] + nome.parte.documento[2]....."

tks